# JAVA Super Mario make Mario fall on gap

Tags: java

my problem is very simple: I have a hard time finding a solution to make Mario fall when he walks on gap(empty space, no ground). If you know an effective way of doing this, please let me know. Also, let me know if you need my explanation of my code if you don't understand, thanks!

```
public class SuperMario extends JPanel {

 static BufferedImage brick;
 static BufferedImage groundb;
 static BufferedImage one;   static BufferedImage onef; 
 static BufferedImage two;   static BufferedImage twof;
 static BufferedImage three;   static BufferedImage threef;
 static BufferedImage four;   static BufferedImage fourf;
 static BufferedImage five;   static BufferedImage fivef;
 static BufferedImage six;   static BufferedImage sixf;
 static BufferedImage seven;   static BufferedImage sevenf;
 static BufferedImage eight;   static BufferedImage eightf;
 boolean gameover=false;
 boolean movenow=false;
 boolean left=false;
 boolean right=true;
 boolean jump=false;
 int jumpmax=0;
 int step=0;
 int frame=0;
 boolean framebegin=false;
 boolean grounded=true;
 int x1=1;
 public final int map[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
 int size=map.length;
 boolean movemap=false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Super Mario"); 
    SuperMario content = new SuperMario();
    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setSize(1200, 800);
    window.setLocation(100,0);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    window.setResizable(false);  // User can't change the window's size.
    window.setVisible(true);

        try {
            brick = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/brick.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            groundb = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/ground.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            one = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/1.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            two = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/2.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            three = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/3.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            four = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/4.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            five = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/5.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            six = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/6.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            seven = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/7.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            eight = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/8.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            onef = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/1f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            twof = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/2f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            threef = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/3f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fourf = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/4f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fivef = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/5f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sixf = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/6f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sevenf = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/7f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            eightf = ImageIO.read(new File("SuperMario/8f.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}

SuperMario(){

    ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(framebegin){
                frame++;
                if(frame>=100&&jump){   
                }
                else if(frame>=100&&!jump){
                    frame=0;
                    framebegin=false;
                    step=0;
                }
            }
            if(mario.centerX<0)
                mario.centerX=0;
            repaint();
        }
    };

    ActionListener actionanimation = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(mario.animation==8){
                mario.animation=1; movenow=false;}
        if(mario.animation<=8&&movenow){
            mario.animation++;
        }
        repaint();
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer( 20, action );
    marioanimation = new Timer (100, actionanimation);

    addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            requestFocus();
        }
    } );

    addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {

        public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
            timer.start();
            marioanimation.start();
            repaint();
        }
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
            timer.stop();
            marioanimation.stop();
            repaint();
        }
    } );

    addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            int code = evt.getKeyCode(); 
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT&&mario.centerY==555&&!movemap) {
                left=true; right=false; movenow=true;
                    mario.centerX-=30;
                step++; framebegin=true;
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT&&mario.centerY==555&&!movemap) {
                right=true; left=false; movenow=true;
                if(mario.centerX>=600){
                    movemap=true;
                }
                if(!movemap)
                    mario.centerX+=30;
                else if(movemap&&mario.centerX!=600)
                    mario.centerX-=20;
                step++; framebegin=true;;
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP&&mario.centerY==555&&!jump) {
                jump=true;}
        }
    } );
}

public Ground ground;
public Mario mario;
public Timer timer;
public Timer marioanimation;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    if(ground==null){
        ground = new Ground();
        mario = new Mario();
    }
    ground.draw(g);
    mario.draw(g);
}

public class Ground implements ImageObserver {
int centerX=0, centerY=0;
int newx=0;
int nbr=1;

void draw(Graphics g){
    for(int y = 1; y<4; y++){
    centerY=y*50+580;
    for(int x=1; x<size; x++){
    centerX=(x-1)*50+newx;
    if(movemap){
        newx-=20;
        movemap=false;
    }
    if(map[x]==1){
    g.drawImage(groundb, centerX, centerY, 50, 50, this);
    }   
    }
    }

}
@Override
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}

public class Mario implements ImageObserver {
int centerX=0;
int centerY=555;
int animation=1;

void draw(Graphics g){

    if(jump&&jumpmax!=300&&step<3){
        centerY-=15;
        jumpmax+=15;
    }

    if(centerY==555){
        jumpmax=0;
    }

    if(jump&&jumpmax!=300&&right&&step>=3){
        centerY-=15;
        jumpmax+=15;
        centerX+=15;
    }
    else if(jump&&jumpmax!=300&&left&&step>=3){
        centerY-=15;
        jumpmax+=15;
        centerX-=15;
    }

    if(jumpmax==300&&centerY!=555&&right){
        centerY+=15;
        jump=false;
        step=0;
    }
    if(jumpmax==300&&centerY!=555&&left){
        centerY+=15;
        jump=false;
        step=0;
    }
    if(jumpmax==300&&centerY!=555&&step<3){
        centerY+=15;
        jump=false;
        step=0;
    }
    if(right){
        if(animation==1){
        g.drawImage(one, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==2){
            g.drawImage(two, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==3){
            g.drawImage(three, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==4){
            g.drawImage(four, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==5){
            g.drawImage(five, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==6){
            g.drawImage(six, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==7){
            g.drawImage(seven, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        if(animation==8){
            g.drawImage(eight, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
        }
        else if(left){
            if(animation==1){
                g.drawImage(onef, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==2){
                    g.drawImage(twof, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==3){
                    g.drawImage(threef, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==4){
                    g.drawImage(fourf, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==5){
                    g.drawImage(fivef, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==6){
                    g.drawImage(sixf, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==7){
                    g.drawImage(sevenf, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                if(animation==8){
                    g.drawImage(eightf, centerX, centerY, 75, 75, this);}
                }
 }
@Override
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}

}
```

Comment: You've posted quite a lot of code, most of it quite redundant, most of it completely unrelated to the problem at hand -- your question. Please be kind to us and try to remember that we're all volunteers -- so please show only code relevant to your problem, best if you could create and post a valid [mcve] -- please read the link.

Comment: Note, that if your program were built in an M-V-C fashion, one where the model is distinctly separate from the view, it would be much easier to create your [mcve] since your program would already be refactored and would already have much higher cohesion and lower coupling.

Answer (score 0):

First off, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We want to help you, but you should at least not make it harder for us.

Anyway, let's go to your question now.

Well, from what I can read from your code, I can see that map[] is the ground. I am assuming that 1 is a block of ground, and 0 is a gap. If that is so, I'll attempt to continue with my explanation.

What I would do is divide the screen into as many columns as how any elements in the map[] array. For example, if you have 20 elements in the map array, the program should divide the screen into 20 columns. Each element in the array corresponds to one column on the screen.

Then, Mario's x-value should be checked, the program should check what section he is in. If his section has a 0 in the map array, he should fall. If the map array has a 1, then he is on ground.